# Showing differents label's position for the same vector object in two different view maps in the QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style, print-composer

I´m trying to do a "detail map" (one window with a bigger scale of one part of the map) over my "main map" in the print composer. But in this detail map I need to change the position of the labels in some specific objects of my vector's layer, but the problem is that the "Lock layers for map item" option does not lock this.

For example in these images:

1) The position of the labels in red is this for the "main map" (scale 1:1000)
[image]

2) The position of the labels in the "detail map" should be more close to the objects, like this:
[image]

3) But if I change the position like in the image above, in the "main map" the labels will be shown like that:
[image]
The labels are over the objects and even some of them are hidden

There is any way to do that?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I´m using QGIS 2.18.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally lock both layers and styles and it always works:

[image]

This operation is only done on one of the two maps.

Comment: Strange, because I´m doing exactly the same thing that you do in the image below and it doesn't work for me...

When I change the label position on the QGIS canvas, it changes in both main and detail map...

Comment: @LeoNazareth I have just done another test and it still works. If `Map 0` is the bigger map and `Map 1` is the smaller map, remember to do this operation when the `Map 0` (or the `Map 1`) is selected in the items legend. Furthermore, remember to click on the `Refresh view` button for refreshing the map view...

Comment: Actually I've tried it now again, and it really works to the style changes, the Map 1 show the change and the Map 0 that is locked doesn't. But the problem persist when I change the label's position, It changes on both maps...

Comment: @LeoNazareth, your issue seems to be only related to labeling. My test was performed using labels, so I think that the best would be editing the question by describing more in detail the steps that lead to the issue.